# 'Cannot set property "innerHTML" of undefined'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a pretty simple script to set an element's innerHTML to the time. However, Javascript keeps throwing a "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined" error. During debugging, I've simplified my script to the point that it runs right after element (a `<span>`) is coded, so I know it should have loaded already. I've also tried running this script as a `<body onload=` argument - same error. I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
<div style="position: fixed; right: 10px; top: 10px; width: auto; font-size: 16pt; border: 2px solid #000000;">
    <span id="clock">Loading...</span>
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        function setClock(spanid){
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById[spanid].innerHTML = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds;
        }
        setClock("clock");
    </script>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not calling `getElementById`, you are attempting to index it. Since it is not an array and does not expose array-like behavior, the result is `undefined`. Replace your `getElementById[spanId]` with `getElementById(spanId)`.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` instead of `()` in `document.getElementById(spanid)`. `getElementById` is function, it has to be invoked with `()` and pass the parameter inside it.

Also missing `()` after `getSeconds()`

```
<div style="position: fixed; right: 10px; top: 10px; width: auto; font-size: 16pt; border: 2px solid #000000;">
    <span id="clock">Loading...</span>
    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        function setClock(spanid){
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById(spanid).innerHTML = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
        }
        setClock("clock");
    </script>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MpCWS/)

Answer (score 2):

change `[]` to `()`:

```
function setClock(spanid){
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById(spanid).innerHTML = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

And now that you have this fixxed add this:

```
 setInterval(function () {
     function setClock(spanid) {
         var d = new Date();
         document.getElementById(spanid).innerHTML = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
     }
     setClock("clock");
 }, 1);
```

And you have an actual clock :D

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Gk3/)**